# onClick function is not working in ReactJs on Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJs. I am trying to achieve onClick functionality on a button to change the text between `<h1>` tag.
Here is the code

```
class MessageStateComponent extends Component{

  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        message: 'Subscribe to NewsLetter'
    }
  }

  changeMessage(){

    this.setState({
        message: 'Thank You'
    })

  }

  render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
            <button onClick = {this.changeMessage}>Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    )
  }

}

export default MessageStateComponent
```

On clicking the button I am getting this error in the console

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
> changeMessage      src/components/MessageStateComponent.js:30
> 27 |         28 | changeMessage(){       29 |
>
> > 30 |     this.setState({
> > | ^  31 |         message: 'Thank You'        32 |     })         33 |

#### EDIT: When I change

`<button onClick = {this.changeMessage}>Subscribe</button>`
to
`<button onClick = {this.changeMessage()}>Subscribe</button>`

I am getting this error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the function in the constructor

```js
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    message: 'Subscribe to NewsLetter'
  }

  this.changeMessage = this.changeMessage.bind(this)
}
```

If you use `create-react-app` it has support for class properties so you can change the function into an arrow function which will bind it automatically(because arrow functions doesn't have `this` context)

If you are using `webpack` you can add the [class-properties plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

```js
changeMessage = () => {
  this.setState({
    message: 'Thank You'
  })
}
```

On the way, if you are have access to class properties through `create-react-app` or any other plugin, you can omit the `constructor` and just use class properties

```js
class MessageStateComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    message: 'Subscribe to NewsLetter'
  }

  changeMessage = () => {
    this.setState({
      message: 'Thank You'
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeMessage}>Subscribe</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear the capes :) It worked. Thank you so much @Asaf Aviv